# Code in jsfiddle not working that runs locally with expected results

Tags: angularjs

I've got a very simple example of a short angularjs app that works correctly when I run it on my local server.  Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkellner99/9sd6ggoq/3/

and the code is quite simple

```
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myVal = 'ABCDE';
    }]);

}());
```

I get an error regarding app not injected correctly and the expression {{ myVal }} does not evaluate.

Comment: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, you're declaring your controller as part of a different module. No module named 'myApp' exists and you have incorrect dot syntax. Change the code to this:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myVal = 'ABCDE';
}]);
```

Then, set the JS load to 'no wrap in head' in the fiddle.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9sd6ggoq/15/)

Comment: thanks @isherwood.  I never noticed the location for the js code inserted.  Also, stupid error on my part with myApp.  I just missed that even though i looked at it 10x.  Time for a new year I think.